# git push failing 'do not amend merges not made by you' when pushing to gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I am currently in the process of moving from gitlab to gerrit and am trying to move a repo that was originally cloned from github to gitlab it has then had multiple commits.

The process I am trying to use is:

```
git clone <gitlab repo>
cd <repo>
git remote add new-origin <newly created gerrit project>
git push new-origin
```

This works for all of the repos apart from one. Which gives me the following:

```
$ git push new-origin
Counting objects: 2292, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (819/819), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2292/2292), 188.26 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2292 (delta 1142), reused 2287 (delta 1138)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1142/1142)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
To <newly created gerrit project>
 ! [remote rejected] production -> production (do not amend merges not made by you)
error: failed to push some refs to '<newly created gerrit project>'`
```

If I try the same thing on the original repo cloned from github it works without a problem.

Can anyone tell me what the message means and how to fix the push.

This is the Gerrit code but I am not clear what it is objecting to:

```
public List<CommitValidationMessage> onCommitReceived(
    CommitReceivedEvent receiveEvent) throws CommitValidationException {
  final PersonIdent author = receiveEvent.commit.getAuthorIdent();
  if (receiveEvent.commit.getParentCount() > 1
      && author.getName().equals(gerritIdent.getName())
      && author.getEmailAddress().equals(gerritIdent.getEmailAddress())
      && !refControl.canForgeGerritServerIdentity()) {
    throw new CommitValidationException("do not amend merges not made by you");
  }
  return Collections.<CommitValidationMessage>emptyList();
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this is Gerrit-specific and comes from line 418 of https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/d168b81bbb288cd5ad31c8d1bb1be513a31e9917/gerrit-server/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/server/git/validators/CommitValidators.java

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message. In my case, the administrator of my Gerrit server had to grant me Forge Author and Forge Server permissions for me to do a successful push.